# Cygwin stops after Norton antivirus install

Tags: cygwin

Cygwin was working fine before I install Norton on my laptop. Cygwin window not even shows the  command prompt. How to fix this? I am using Win7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: norton sucks + win7 sucks = everything blows up ;) try asking on http://superuser.com/ anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Norton is high up on Cygwin's Big List Of Dodgy Applications at http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda. These applications often install hooks into other processes, yet they don't do so entirely transparently, thereby breaking crucial Cygwin functionality, in particular its `fork()` implementation.

So far MS's Security Essentials appears to be Cygwin-compatible, but these things change ...